# rake db:migrate does not create table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rake

I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and have strange error (learning rails with the HeadFirst book, project and directory name - "mebay"):

I need to create project uses only "read" of CRUD - so I run:

```
~/mebay $ rails generate model ad name:string description:text price:decimal seller_id:integer email:string img_url:string

Running via Spring preloader in process 8400
      invoke  active_record
   identical    db/migrate/20161018144410_create_ads.rb
   identical    app/models/ad.rb
      invoke    test_unit
   identical      test/models/ad_test.rb
   identical      test/fixtures/ads.yml
```

and here comes my db/migrate/20161018144410_create_ads.rb:

```
class CreateAds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ads do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.decimal :price
      t.integer :seller_id
      t.string :email
      t.string :img_url

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

(looks pretty ok for me, basing on earlier projects)

Then, as I understand, I need to create database (i use sqlite):

```
~/mebay $ rake db:migrate
```

but after that, my development.sqlite3 remain empty

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: After you perform `rake db:migrate` what was the logs says?

Comment: @araratan, 
`~/mebay $ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually didn't do anything wrong. Look in db/schema.rb and if you see this then you're database is setup properly:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161019035406) do

  create_table "ads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.integer  "seller_id"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "img_url"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

end
```

If you're getting an error that the table already exists, you can do the following:

first add a `down` method to your migration file that you used to generate the ads table. The down method would look like this:

```
def down
  drop_table :ads
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=version_number` where the version_number is the timestamp in the name of the migration file. This will remove the table from the database. Then change the name of the `change` method to `up`. Save the file and run `rake db:migrate:up` to create the table again.

Comment: Yeah you're right but.. But the books says I need to replace my database with downloaded from their site (according to book - with the same structure)

but after replacing i get
http://localhost:3000/ads/3:

`Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

      def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
        raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)
      end

      def load_schema_if_pending!`

Comment: and then
`~/mebay $ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20161018144410 CreateAds: migrating ========================================
-- create_table(:ads)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "ads" already exists: CREATE TABLE "ads" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar, "description" text, "price" decimal, "seller_id" integer, "email" varchar, "img_url" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) `

Comment: Oh you need to drop the table first before running your migration. The error output said `SQLite3::SQLException: table "ads" already exists`. To drop the table, run this command `rails generate migration drop_ads_table`. Then open that new migration file and copy this string into the body of the def method `drop_table :ads`. Save the file and then run rake db:migrate

Comment: ahem.. :) you meaned rake db:drop? (just googled it)

Comment: ahem.. :) you meaned rake db:drop? (just googled it)

`~/mebay $ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20161018144410 CreateAds: migrating ========================================
-- create_table(:ads)
   -> 0.0012s
== 20161018144410 CreateAds: migrated (0.0013s) ===============================`

as i expected, dropping erased all of the data) 
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AdsController#show
Couldn't find Ad with 'id'=3`

but how can i actually replace the tables then, if they had same structure?

Comment: I just amended my answer. And no I didn't mean that. Running `rake db:drop` will completely erase the whole database and the way I proposed will simply delete the ads table from the database. I suppose either way would work for your situation though.

Comment: it half-worked) or I half-understanded it. :)
I did what you said with replaced table file and come back to `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AdsController#show
Couldn't find Ad with 'id'=3`
maybe there is another way to replace sqlite files?

Comment: whoops - you was totally right, my code was ok from the very beginning, problem was in the downloaded database. Manyally edited my db with sqlitestudio and that's all. You're my hero

Answer (score 0):

How about run `rake db:create` first and then run `rake db:migrate`